# C#: Intersection between custom rectangular class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, intersection

I'm trying to create a function to check for overlapping between my rectangular custom class "Room".
Basically I want to run for loop to separate all rooms in my game from eachother.

So I'm looking to be able to check 2 rooms against each other, using their starting position (lower left corner of the room) and the height and width to check if their areas overlap. I'm not sure what the best way to go around this would be. Basically my thought was checking each horizontal "line"/side against the vertical lines of the other room, and vice versa. But then I'm not sure what the best way to go about that is.

Thanks in advance!

My Room class is basically:

```
public class Room {
    public Point position {get; set;}
    public int width {get; set;}
    public int height {get; set;}

    public Room(Point p, int w, int h) {
        position = p;
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    public bool Intersects(Room other) {
        //This is where I need help.
    }
}
```

Where Point looks like this, basically to avoid floats/doubles.

```
public class Point {
    public int x {get; set;}
    public int y {get; set;}

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't there any built-in function for intersection check ?

Comment: I think your idea is the common solution and probably other implementations have very similar algorithm.

Comment: Your `Room` class is virtually the same as `System.Drawing.Rectangle`, which has a built-in `Intersects` method.  Do you really need more properties than starting position, height, and width?

Comment: Take a look at the IntersectsWith method, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.intersectswith%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Troy, I realize that. But I don't know where I can see the source for Intersects? I don't want to cast my room to a Rectangle if I could avoid it (which I definitely could) ?

Answer (score 0):

Everything starts in Your mind, so grab a pen and paper :)

**1.** Draw a Room and bold bottom left corner as it is Your Point (lets call it PointA).
**2.** Draw a Point (PointB) inside Room and check what coordinates are in relation to Your Point, You will see correlation (PointB.X <= PointA + Room width and PointB.Y <= PointB + Room height)

Do the same switching Points and remember that int can have negative values

Cheers !

Comment: Aye, yes, thanks :) I was wondering about doing something like that. But then it seems I'd have to loop till I find a point in the  box that is inside, then return true, otherwise return false.
Isn't it possible to mathematically calculate it using each corner? Or did you mean to just check each four corner? Because that won't always be right then.

Answer (score 0):

Everething is simple enough. There are many options - it's one of them:

```
    public bool Intersects(Room other)
    {
        if (other ==  null)
            return false;

        var r1 = new { Left = this.position.X, Right = this.position.X + this.width, Bottom = this.position.Y, Top = this.position.Y + this.height };
        var r2 = new { Left = other.position.X, Right = other.position.X + other.width, Bottom = other.position.Y, Top = other.position.Y + other.height };

        return r2.Right > r1.Left && r2.Bottom < r1.Top && r2.Top > r1.Bottom && r2.Left < r1.Right;
    }
```

Comment: Oooh, yeah, I was looking for something like that.
Why do you do !( ||  ||  || ||) ?

Comment: Yeah, you right! I have forgot inversions. Let's simplfy expression. (I've modify the answer)

Comment: Oh, I just wondered why you even did the inversions to begin with :)

Comment: I've just try to use De Morgan's laws to minify expression - it works wrong cause forgotten inversion I've mentioned above.